# Lista Encadeada (inserção no fim)

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer uma lista encadeada com inserção no fim dela, mas na hora de escrever da erro e não sei qual o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cel
{
    int v;
    struct cel *prox;
};
typedef struct cel celula;

int main()
{
    celula *inicio;
    inicio = NULL;
    inserefim(&inicio);
    escreve(inicio);
    return 0;
}

void inserefim(celula **ini)
{
    celula *aux;
    celula **fim;
    int x;
    do{
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if(x)
        {
            if(*ini == NULL){
                aux =(celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula));
                aux->v = x;
                aux->prox = NULL;
                *ini = aux;
                *fim = aux;
            }else{
                aux = (celula*)malloc(sizeof(celula));
                aux->v = x;
                (*fim)->prox = aux;
                aux->prox = NULL;
            }

        }
    }while(x);
}

void escreve(celula *ini)
{
    while(ini =! NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNUM:%d",ini->v);
        ini= ini->prox;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na função `inserefim` tem alguns acertos a fazer:

- `celula **fim;` o ponteiro para o fim não precisa de ser duplo, um ponteiro simples é suficiente o que simplifica o código
- Faltou no `else` voltar apontar o ponteiro `fim` para `aux`:

  ```
  if(*ini == NULL){
      ...
  }else{
      ...
      //aqui
  }
  ```

  Repare também que o código que tem no `if` e no `else` é grande parte repetido. Quando é esse o caso deve tentar colocar o que é igual antes ou depois do `if ... else` de forma a não se repetir e tornar o código mais simples.

Escreva então a sua função `inserefim` assim:

```
void inserefim(celula **ini)
{
    celula *aux;
    celula *fim; //ponteiro simples
    int x = 1;
    do{
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if(x)
        {
            aux =(celula*) malloc(sizeof(celula)); //era igual no if else
            aux->v = x; //era igual no if else
            aux->prox = NULL; //era igual no if else

            if(*ini == NULL){
                *ini = aux;
            }else{
                fim->prox = aux;
            }

            fim = aux; //agora executa tanto no if como no else
        }
    }while(x);
}
```

No função `escreve` também se enganou no operador diferente `!=`:

```
while(ini =! NULL)
// -------^ está =! quando devia estar !=
```

Este tipo de distrações são muito fáceis de apanhar no compilador. Ora veja o *warning* que ele dá neste caso com o operador diferente escrito ao contrário:

> ||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>
> ...main.c||In function 'escreve':|
>
> ...main.c|13|warning: assignment
>   makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
>
> ...main.c|13|warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as
>   truth value [-Wparentheses]|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

Isto reforça a ideia de que é muito importante olhar para os avisos dados. Quando está a começar ou quando ainda não tem muita experiencia você quer considerar todos os avisos como erros mesmo, pois na verdade a maior parte deles são coisas que não está a fazer corretamente, e que terão implicações mais tarde.

[Veja o código com as alterações indicadas no Ideone](https://ideone.com/rGKEhW)